# when redrawing the table, I need to prevent expanded rows from closing

Tags: c++, windows, qt, model-view-controller

In my Windows C++ application, I use Qt to draw a table with drop down rows. Everything works well, but the problem is that: after the table is redrawn, the expanded rows are displayed closed.
[image: table with rows expanded]

To prevent already expanded rows from being closed when the tree is redrawn, I use the following idea: save the state of the expanded elements and restore it after updating the model.
As a model, I use the TreeModel class, which is a descendant of the QAbstractItemModel class.
To implement the idea, I supplemented my class with the following methods:

```
class TreeModel : public QAbstractItemModel {
        Q_OBJECT

private:
        QList<Record> records;          // Table rows are stored here
    std::vector<int> expandedItems; // Set of expanded element identifiers
    QTreeView* treeView;            // Pointer to QTreeView
public:
        explicit TreeModel(QTreeView* view, QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractItemModel(parent), treeView(view) {
    }
        // Other class methods...

        // Method for saving the state of expanded indexes
        void saveExpandedIndexes()
    {
        expandedItems.clear();
        QModelIndex rootIndex = index(0, 0);
        saveExpandedItemsRecursive(rootIndex);
    }

        // Recursive Method for Saving the State of Expanded Indexes
    void saveExpandedItemsRecursive(const QModelIndex& parentIndex)
    {
        int rowCount = this->rowCountModel(parentIndex);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row)
        {
            QModelIndex childIndex = index(row, 0, parentIndex);
            if (childIndex.isValid() && treeView->isExpanded(childIndex))
            {
                int itemId = getItemId(childIndex);
                expandedItems.push_back(itemId);
                saveExpandedItemsRecursive(childIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    // Method for restoring the state of expanded indexes
    void restoreExpandedItems()
    {
        foreach(const Record & record, records)
        {
            if (expandedItems.contains(record.id))
            {
                QModelIndex itemIndex = indexById(record.id);
                if (itemIndex.isValid())
                {
                    treeView->setExpanded(itemIndex, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int rowCountModel(const QModelIndex& parent) const
    {//Helper method that will return the number of children for the specified parent index
        if (!parent.isValid())
        {
            // If parent is not a valid index,
            // return the number of root elements
            return records.size();
        }
        // Get the ID of the parent element
        int parent_id = parent.internalId();
        // Get a list of child ids for a parent element
        QVector<int> child_Ids = childIds(parent_id);
        // Returning the number of child elements
        return child_Ids.size();
    }
    int getItemId(const QModelIndex& index) const
    {// Helper method to get element id by index
        if (!index.isValid())
            return -1;

        return index.internalId();
    }
        QVector<int> childIds(int parent_id) const
        {
            QVector<int>  ret;
            for (auto& r : records)
                if (r.parent_id == parent_id)
                     ret.push_back(r.id);
            return ret;
        }

}
```

Next in my program I create a model:

```
ModelTable = new TreeModel(pTableForm->ui.treeView, this);
```

I set the model to display it

```
pTableForm->ui.treeView->setModel(ModelTable);
```

When a table needs to be redrawn, I use my idea like this:

```
        ModelTable->saveExpandedItems();  // this is where I store the states of the expanded strings
        ModelTable->clear();              // all model records are deleted here
        Fill_Tree_ModelTable(ModelTable); // here all model rows are created again
        dataChanged(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex()); // signal that the data has changed
        ModelTable->restoreExpandedItems(); // here I'm trying to restore the state of expanded rows
```

After that, I get my table again, however, all rows are shown closed.
Tell me what I need to fix so that after redrawing I get open those lines that were expanded before redrawing

Comment: Simply don't recreate the table every time but properly use the appropriate signals when you model changes so the view knows what to redraw: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#details